# REST API design for cross entity queries

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

As REST API builder I have faced this problem few times without a good solution:

Having an entity organization it seems clear that we can REST model it as /organization with all the pack (GET, POSt, PUT, DELETE, filtering, paging, ...)

NOTE that I am using Spring with @RestController classes and spring-data PagingAndSortingRepository injected into the controller.

The problem starts with

/organization/{id}/users

which is a perfect URL for a REST API but starts to cause some pain.

If we follow the path of processing the request in organization controller we will need to add UserDAO to the controller, so we can end with many DAOS injected in every controller, and every controller responsible of returning lots of different objects: organizations, users, models, etc.

Pushing the problem to the DAO layer is not a solution; Trying to make the repositories to return all these different objects will not work (PagingAndSortingRepository shall complain if we try to work with different entities) and it does not feels like the right thing because we force repositories to work with entities out of its domain.

Using a intermediate layer between controllers and DAOs could work, a service layer that can hold those different DAOs and offer a single facade, but again feels wrong: First the controller is still working with many different objects that do not belong its domain, Second we have a layer with no real purpose that can grow with combinations of DAOs, or having a great master DAO object able to query anything.

What is the good way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had similar problem several times and came with generic solution. Lets first redefine the problem: in your Service or Controller you will need to perform an action which could have different types. (In your case you need to access an Object that at different runtimes could be user, organization model or something else. Each type of access is performed by a separate bean and it is not desirable to inject all of those beans into your Service/Controller.

The solution is a Factory pattern. Here is what I did: I created an Interface and an abstract class implementing this interface for the action. (In your case it would be something like GenericDao and GenericDaoImpl). Then I created Factory class (Say GeneralDaoFactory). This class holds a map `Map<String, GenericDao>`In my generic class I wrote a constructor that adds itself into the Factory. Factory receives a name (Usually a class name) and an instance of GenericDao and places it into its internal map. Then you just write your classes implementing GenericDaoImpl (OrganizationDaoImpl, UserDaoImpl etc) and make sure they are defined as beans. Spring during initialization will instantiate all beans and each bean running its constructor will place itself into the factory. So now in your code in your Controller/Service all you will need to do:

```
GenericDao userDao = GeneralDaoFactory.getInstance("UserDaoImpl");
GenericDao organizationDao = GeneralDaoFactory.getInstance("OrganizationDaoImpl");
```

The factory will be initialized behind the scienes by Spring, and you don't need to inject any of those daos in advance. You just need to know their names and know which one you need at the moment. Also once you need to add a new Dao, all you need to do is to actuially write its implementatin and it is now available from your factory

Comment: mmm ... not sure to understand because you are injecting both DAOs at the end ... but I think maybe your suggestion is to have generic controllers with generic DAOs and a mechanism that will identify which DAOs are required for a specific request and will instantiate at runtime an specific controller with specific DAOs to serve that specific request. It this it?

Comment: @Rafael you missunderstood. First of all no generic controllers - just your regular controller. Second no DAO gets injected at all, they are just created as beans by Spring but not injected anywhere. But you have a factory that keeps a reference to them - each bean puts itself into factory map in its constructor. Then in your controller at the runtime you can get any DAO through the factory

Answer (score 0):

You state `/organization/{id}/users` *is a perfect URL for a REST API*.

It is a reasonable URL, however I would argue that since the URL crosses domains it **can only be used for searching**.

In addition, single responsibility is enforced to limit the number of DAOs per controller. The supporting controller for the above URL would be something like `OrganizationUsersSearchController`.  Presumably, the method returns a `List<User> users` for the requested `id`.  This class interacts with the `OrganzationsDAO`to get some context, and the context is passed to the UsersDAO to get the list of users.  The DAOs could be wrapped by a service class so the controller is just a facade.

Once the client has the list of `users`, CRUD operations are invoked by the client using the single domain URL such as `/users/{userId}`.  The `UserController` only interacts with the `UsersDAO`.  Again, perhaps wrap the DAO in a service class so the controller is just a facade.

Comment: "can only be used for searching." ... I can agree that, still seems like a very solid rest URL. "single responsibility is enforced to limit the number of DAOs per controller" EXACTLY that's the starting point of the question. Now what I argue is that OrganizationUsersSearchController looks like a poor solution to me since the controller will start to multiply ... we will end with a potentially lot of controllers ad-hoc in order to support these operations also routing will be complex since starting part of URl is same.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your intent is to get the list of users for a given organization Id, this is the way to go, keeping the `OrganizationController` and its JPA domain layer untouched. It seems to me just a query on the users' table. `UsersController` can have `UsersService` calling JPA layer to filter all objects of users for the given organization Id. I agree this confusion comes often when we read multiple blogs showing multiple different standards of REST API notations.

```
GET /users?orgId={id}
```